# Sidebar menu and main content on modern mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to avoid scrolling on the main content in mobile browsers when a sidebar menu is opened ° by adding a class to the main content with a 100% height, a hidden overflow and an absolute position, but the problem is if I scroll down and then open the menu I get automatically moved to the top of the page and don't stay on the position where I was before opening the sidebar. I can't figure out what's going wrong.

I tried some solutions like saving the position and then forcing the window to stay always at that place until the sidebar is closed, but I'm pretty sure there's a cleaner way to do it.

Anyone has a better idea?

Thank you very much.

° (I think the technique is known as "off canvas")

Answer (score 0):

You must have put the sidebar at the top of your page, thats why it scrolls to top. To solve this, just use `position:absolute;`